# Regrouting an indoor pool

Tags: pool, grout

We have an indoor pool in the basement in a 40 year old home (Finland), the grout in the pool tiles has pretty much disappeared. Can I regrout this as is, or do I need to follow any special directions?

[image]

Comment: All of the TCNA Handbook details for epoxy grout mention using it if subject to chemical attack. I've always assumed that this chemical attack was pool chlorine. My instinct, then, is to use epoxy grout. The instructions for this epoxy grout is where I would look for special directions.